# Executing stanford corenlp coreference resolution

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to execute stanford corenlp package to get coreference resolution.

Here is the command given for coref execution:

```
java -cp <jars_in_corenlp> -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.SieveCoreferenceSystem -props <properties file>
```

I executed like this -

```
java - cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.SieveCoreferenceSystem -props annotators = pos, lemma, ner, parse dcoref.postprocessing = true dcoref.maxdist = -1 -file input.txt

java - cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.SieveCoreferenceSystem -props annotators = pos, lemma, ner, parse dcoref.postprocessing = true dcoref.maxdist = -1 input.txt
```

gives error -

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

This way it works, but it loads all `jar` files, which takes additional time, I want to execute with minimal execution time.

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref -file input.txt
```